# Device limitation rule for user

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a simple application for mobile users, they can login using provided API but must have limitation on the devices, so the requirement is simple :

> User cannot login using more than 2 devices

I'm building the API using laravel for mobile apps, so I've created the function and it works correctly and wrote test and it works fine you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/Gujarats/DeviceLimitation/tree/27cddd7fea36225b17d6e56d6b7eae5818aa83aa).

But I would like to know what are you guys think of this code :

```
public function isLoginValid2($user_id,$device_id){

        $deviceLimit = 2;

        //retrive device or create new one if doesnt exist
        $params = [
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'device_id' => $device_id
        ];

        $device = Device::where($params)->first();

        if (!$device) {

            // check if not exceed limit  
            if (Device::where(['user_id'=>$user_id, 'is_banned'=>false])->count() <= $deviceLimit) {
                return true;
            }else{
                // the device is above llmit
                return false;
            }

        }else {
            // check if banned
            if ($device->is_banned) {
                // the device is banned user is not pemmitted to login
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

As for the code above if we take a look there are some code line that we can modify or move to create another function.

The reason why I did it because I can make a unit test case on every function and make sure everything is work. so the code above I've modified it and become like this :

```
public function isLoginValid2Refactored($user_id,$device_id){
        if($this->isDeviceExistWithUser($user_id,$device_id)){
            //device is exist check if its banned
            if($this->isDeviceBanned($device_id)){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            //device is not exits check device limit
            if($this->isUserReachLimitDevice($user_id)){
                //user reach limit device 
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So from here I created another function called `isDeviceExistWithUser` and `isUserReachLimitDevice` any better idea to write testable?  Or any better improvement so I others can read it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the `return true` and `return false` are too verbose. Just focus on what conditions have to be satisfied to allow the user to return `true`.

```
public function isLoginValid2Refactored($user_id, $device_id) {
    return $this->isDeviceExistWithUser($user_id, $device_id) ?
           !$this->isDeviceBanned($device_id) :
           !$this->isUserReachLimitDevice($user_id);
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, but can you tell me what are those code called? any documentation so I can learn more about this?

Comment: See [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$device = Device::where($params)->first();` will either return an instance of eloquent or `null`.

You have `if (!$device) {...}else{...}`.

This translates to if the device is not found aka the else part then `$device->is_banned` which will results in a trying to get property of non-object fatal error.

---

```
if ($condition) {
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

The `else` is not necessary since `return` will immediately end the execution of the function and return the result.

```
if ($condition) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Works just the same and I personally find it more visually pleasant.

---

`$this->isDeviceExistWithUser($user_id,$device_id)`

Syntax heavy naming. You could simple call it `deviceForUser` or something like that. `is` usually suggests a boolean, as in `isDevice`, `isSmall`, `isLarge` etc etc.

---

`$this->isDeviceBanned($device_id)`

Nitpick but a simple `isBanned` will do here since you passing in `$device_id`, clearly a device is the scope here.

---

`isLoginValid2Refactored`

Again really heavy name here. It's not something inherently wrong with it, but the lighter the better. Fluent and easy to understand goes a long way.

Comment: first I like your suggestion about my heavyNaming variable and function, but on the first paragraph you mention instance of eloquent, I think it will work just fine, cuz it will not go to the condition $device->is_banned when `$device = Device::where($params)->first();` return null

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- `$deviceLimit` should liekly be derived from configuration (class constant, application configuration value, etc.) rather than hardcoded in this single method.
- I don't understand the two different calls against the device static methods.  What value does the first one have?  It seem like you got just get a list of the not banned devices based on user id as in second call and compare the device id against at list. I am guessing your Device class is probably where this logic on whether a device can be added to approved list for user.  I would strive for an interface against the device class that was something like this:

  $device_valid = Device::isDeviceValidForUser($user_id, $device_id);

That would remove for the need for this method in this class altogether. After all, why does a login class need to understand the logic around whether a device is valid for a user?
 - I think `Device` as a class name is probably not the best naming for this class, which seems to expose functionality dealing more with a collection of devices.  Is that class itself doing too much?

Comment: you said `Device` is not the best naming for the class? what is your suggestion then? I name that class cuz it will easy to remember that `Device` class is for getting data from devices table

Comment: Maybe `DeviceProvider`, `DeviceFactory`, `DeviceSelector` or something similar that conveys that this class is intended to supply `Device` objects given some sort of criteria.  Hard to say what is should be called without seeing all the functionality exposed by this class.